Why is my plugin made with @wordpress/create-block is not on Gutenberg editor?
Wordpress & Database version
The same issue on Github
I started my wordpress website with Local.

PHP: 8.2.10
Database: MySQL 8.0.16
WordPress ver: 6.5.3



node -v: v20.14.0
npm -v: 10.7.0

Plugin Creation
under the wp-content/plugins folder, i made new custom-plugin
Here is command and its result.
plugins$ npx @wordpress/create-block custom-plugin

Creating a new WordPress plugin in the custom-plugin directory.

//...

Done: WordPress plugin Custom Plugin bootstrapped in the custom-plugin directory.

You can run several commands inside:

  $ npm start
    Starts the build for development.

 //...

To enter the directory type:

  $ cd custom-plugin

You can start development with:

  $ npm start

Code is Poetry
plugins$ 

The plugin on wp-admin dashboard
after starting the plugin, I saw the plugin itself from admin panel, and I activated it:

The Custom Plugin is not on the Editor
But I cannot see the pluin on the editor...

Anyone encountered the same issue?
npm start output:
custom-plugin npm start

> custom-plugin@0.1.0 start
> wp-scripts start

assets by chunk 17.3 KiB (name: index)
  assets by path *.css 1.83 KiB
    asset index.css 957 bytes [emitted] (name: index) 1 related asset
    asset index-rtl.css 920 bytes [emitted] (name: index)
  asset index.js 15.3 KiB [emitted] (name: index) 1 related asset
  asset index.asset.php 146 bytes [emitted] (name: index)
assets by path ./*.css 1.95 KiB
  asset ./style-index.css 1020 bytes [emitted] (name: ./style-index) (id hint: style) 1 related asset
  asset ./style-index-rtl.css 979 bytes [emitted] (name: ./style-index) (id hint: style)
assets by chunk 1.07 KiB (name: view)
  asset view.js 1010 bytes [emitted] (name: view) 1 related asset
  asset view.asset.php 84 bytes [emitted] (name: view)
asset block.json 515 bytes [emitted] [from: src/block.json] [copied]
Entrypoint view 1.07 KiB (1.14 KiB) = view.js 1010 bytes view.asset.php 84 bytes 1 auxiliary asset
Entrypoint index 19.3 KiB (11.8 KiB) = 6 assets 3 auxiliary assets
runtime modules 5.17 KiB 14 modules
orphan modules 4.83 KiB [orphan] 4 modules
built modules 4.58 KiB (javascript) 474 bytes (css/mini-extract) [built]
  javascript modules 4.13 KiB
    cacheable modules 3.97 KiB
      modules by path ./src/*.js 3.87 KiB 4 modules
      modules by path ./src/*.scss 100 bytes 2 modules
    external ["wp","blocks"] 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
    external ["wp","i18n"] 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
    external ["wp","blockEditor"] 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
    external "ReactJSXRuntime" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
  css modules 474 bytes
    css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].use[3]!./src/style.scss 268 bytes [built] [code generated]
    css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].use[3]!./src/editor.scss 206 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/block.json 455 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.91.0 compiled successfully in 555 ms


Please check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78564902/wordpress-block-not-showing-after-npx-wordpress-create-blocklatest-and-activ

This issue appears to be caused by the recently released @wordpress/scripts 28.0.0 version.
As mentioned by Michael Benker and Vincent Roper, the solution for me was also to downgrade the version.
In my case, the 27.9.0 version worked well.
